# Laravel 5.2 - edit the data from DB in the Model

Tags: php, laravel, model

Can I check and edit data in Model, not in Controller?
For example, now I get data from Model and work with it in Controller.

```
$user = User::select('name','privateflag','lastname')->get();
//name = John, privateflag = 1, lastname = Smith
if ($user->privateflag == 1) {$user->lastname = 'Private';}
//Pass to View: name = John, lastname = Private
```

Can I check and edit data in Model and receive in Controller already updated data? Like this:

```
class User extends ... {
...
//Get from DB: name = John, privateflag = 1, lastname = Smith
if ($user->privateflag == 1) {$user->lastname = 'Private';}
//Pass to Controller: name = John, lastname = Private
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way is to use [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in model like this:

```
class User extends Model {
...
public function getLastNameAttribute()
{
    if ($this->privateflag) {
        return 'Private';
    }
    return $this->attributes['lastname'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to get in accessor the name of the function from Controller that requested this data?